# Saving project creates three layers per one original layer and some files are "no valid data sources"

Tags: qgis, save

It doesn't matter how I save my project (Qconsolidate-Plugin, Relocator-Plugin, QPackage-Plugin or manual), the output is always defective: The export always consists (as shown in the picture) of three layers per one original layer in my original project: One .shp-layer, one .shx-layer and one .dbf-layer.

Additionally the .qgj-file, the .prj-file and the .cpg-file of every layer are "no valid data sources" referring to the defect report of QGIS.

The result is a wrong projection and a wrong symbology.

[image]

[image]

How ist that possible?

Comment: All questions in GIS SE  should be standalone. It is extremely confusing to start a question with a paragraph about some other question. Please remember to give a complete description of your GIS platform environment with each new question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if maybe you're confused about how shapefiles write to disk.

A GIS single layer, when exported as a "shapefile", actually becomes a collection of files on disk, including one `.shp` file and usually also a `.shx`, a `.dbf`, a `.prj`, and a `.cpg` file.

Only the `.shp` will load in QGIS (and QGIS will automatically look for those other files).  If you tried to open the `.prj` or `.cpg` directly QGIS, as you said, it will say they're not valid,  because QGIS expects you to specify the `.shp` file.